# Bootstrap grid with variable row placement

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a page with a grid of images. When the window is large, I would like to display 4 images per row, when it is a medium size, 3 images per row, and when it is small, 2 images per row.

However, Bootstrap's [grid system documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) seems to indicate that the row breaks must be fixed in advance, e.g.:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  ...
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
...
```

Is there a way to use Bootstrap to get the behavior I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line is the row needs to equal 12 to fill up the space. You can have just one row and everything will reflow depending on the viewport:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img></div>
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: That's precisely what I tried to do, but it doesn't seem to work. When the window is large, I get the following layout (where X indicates an image, - indicates a space, and \ indicates a line break): XXXX\---X\X---
       
Where what I want is: XXXX\XX--

Comment: Thats strange. Can you create a jsfiddle or bootply so I can take a look?

Comment: Went to do so and found that I just had a misplaced closing tag :). Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think we have all been there! Cheers.